# 500 error when trying to open Azure Cloud Shell in Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to push changes to my Azure application. I've installed and enabled Azure Login extension for Visual Studio Code and am getting this message when I login to the app through the browser:
"You have signed in to the Visual Studio Code application on your device. You may now close this window."
When I click the "+" symbol in VS Code terminal to add Power Shell in Cloud Shell, I get the following response:

```
Requesting a Cloud Shell...
Connecting terminal...
Error: No referer header. (500)
```

I'm running this setup:
VS Code Version: 1.28.0
Azure Account Extension Version: 0.11.5
OS Version: Ventura 13.4

Comment: Did you configure your subscription in VScode?

Comment: Try this way: 1. Press `CTRL+ SHIFT+P`
2. Type `Open PowerShell in Cloud Shell or Open Bash in Cloud Shell` and enter.

Answer (score 0):

This is an intermittent issue that might come up from the following reasons: -

- Try signing into the Azure account by different browser. Give `CTRL+SHIFT+P` or Goto `View >> command palette` and then search for `Azure: Sign in`. Choose one of the below `sign-in` options if the other one is failing.

[image]

[image]

- After signing in, type  ***Open PowerShell in Cloud Shell***  or  ***Open Bash in Cloud Shell*** in command palette and it will connect you directly to cloud shell as shown. I have just checked with `az --version` command to verify if it is properly working.

[image]

*Note:* As error is mainly pointing towards the `referer header`, check that no browser extensions or settings are blocking this header.

Because this header is frequently used for security and authentication. When connecting to Azure Cloud Shell, ensure that your browser provides the right `referer` header.  If still the issue persists, try logging in private browser to avoid cache and extension blockers.

- Make sure the Azure accounts & Azure CLI extensions in Vscode are up to date. If required update with the latest extension versions of [Azure accounts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azure-account) & [Azure CLI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azurecli). Reload the mentioned extensions and then try again.
- Check the `VScode` version and update it to the latest. Restarting Visual Studio Code may resolve the issue in few cases.
- If your logged-in Azure account has multiple subscriptions, ensure that you have configured your current subscription before requesting to access cloud shell.
- Browser cookies may sometimes trigger authentication issues. Clear your browser's cookies and cache and try again.